# Using Threads in Swift causes memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, swift5, xcode12.5

I encountered a strange behaviour in my application when using Threads inside my ViewModel. It seems something is happening in Thread.init which causes a memory leak even when the deinit of the Thread object is called (I'm not even starting the thread).

I'm relatively new to Swift so it might be my fault but I don't know why. I have two Views linked together via a NavigationView. The child View has a ViewModel which creates a Thread when the initialization method is called and destroys the Thread object when the deinitialization method is called. The deinitialization method of the ViewModel is called when the child View is "closed". After navigating back to the parent View I can see in the Memory Profiler of Xcode that there is a new memory leak

[image]

I post a small example which reproduces this issue below

**The HomeView:** (main view)

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    @State private var showView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: TestView(showView: self.$showView), isActive : self.$showView) {
                    Text("Open MainView")
                }.isDetailLink(false)
                .navigationBarTitle("Home")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The TestView:** (child view)

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    
    @Binding var showView : Bool
    
    @StateObject var mainViewModel = TestViewViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Back") {
            showView = false
        }.onAppear(perform: {
            mainViewModel.initViewModel()
        })
        .onDisappear(perform: {
            mainViewModel.deinitViewModel()
        })
    }
}
```

**The ViewModel:**

```
import Foundation

class TestViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    private var testThread: TestThread?
    
    public func initViewModel() {
        testThread = TestThread.init()
    }
    
    public func deinitViewModel() {
        testThread?.cancel()
        testThread = nil
    }
    
    
    /*+++++++++++++++*/
    /*+ Test thread +*/
    /*+++++++++++++++*/

    private class TestThread: Thread {

        override init(){
            print("Init RenderThread")
        }
        
        deinit {
            print("deinit RenderThread")
        }

        override func main() {
            
        }
    }
}
```

That's it, no magic involved but when clicking the **Back** button in the child view it seems something will not be garbage collected in the ViewModel's Thread. Any hints what might be wrong? Is this a bug or is there something I have to release manually?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you should almost never use `Thread` in iOS programming (or macOS or watchOS or tvOS for that matter).  Use Grand Central Dispatch queues or `Operation` blocks

Comment: Your code, as shown, actually does release the thread because you don't `start` it.  As soon as you `start` it you will see the leak.  Seriously, though, use Grand Central Dispatch.

Comment: Change `@ObservedObject var mainViewModel = TestViewViewModel()` to `@StateObject var mainViewModel = TestViewViewModel()` it will cause a leak

Comment: @loremipsum why is ObservedObject causing a leak? Can you explain that?

Comment: @Paulw11 did you check with the XCode Memory profiler? I see the leak even when I do not start the thread. Just calling the init function of the thread is enough and as soon as you close the child view you see in the memory profiler that something wasn't cleaned up properly. I already use GCD but I have some parts in my code where I prefer to have control of my threads (priority, cancelation etc.) rather than let the GCD manage them internally.

Comment: From your screenshot it seems that Thread leaks its `threadDictionary`, you could log a developer ticket with Apple and see what they say.

Comment: @Paulw11 okay thanks, yes I've already created a bug ticket. Let's see what's the outcome

Comment: You are [initialing the “wrong” way](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app). SO has many posts where when people initialize as you are doing they get leaks. Use ObservedObject when the object is coming from the previous view and StateObject when you are initializing in the same view

Comment: @loremipsum yes sorry you are absolutely right. I watched some Swift MVVM tutorials now and read some more in the documentation. Sorry I'm an Android developer and I started programing Swift a couple of months ago. Anyway the initial problem remains but thanks a lot for the useful hint.

Comment: NP it is a common thing. A lot of people are doing what you were doing because it was a common thing when StateObject didn’t exist (iOS 13)

Comment: @grill2010 you found some unexpected behaviour of Cocoa, the problem is reproducible with a simple class, no need for SwiftUI or ObservableObject, thus you can simplify the code from the question to get it in a better shape.